# Export Contacts from a shared "non-default" folder in outlook to excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In our company we have a shared Outlook contact folder that we need to regularly export to a csv file. I'm trying to create a Macro Enabled Workbook to make it automated. The contact folder is not a default contact folder for any user. One user created it and shared it with other users. It shows up in our outlook on the contacts pane under Shared Contacts in the format Sharing Username - Folder Name (example Matt Prater - Matt's File). As documented everywhere, you can't easily export from such a folder with the Outlook Export wizard. So I'm turning to VBA.

Note - all users are Microsoft Exchange users with exchange accounts. We are using Office 365 - not the web app.

I've tried using the NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder("Matt Prater", olFolderContacts) method in the code below, but the folder is not the default contact folder for Matt.

```
Sub ExportSharedContacts()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olRecipient As Recipient
Dim olItems As Items
Dim olItem As Object
Dim olFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim i As Integer
Dim row As Range

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olRecipient = olNS.CreateRecipient("Matt Prater")
olRecipient.Resolve
Set olFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecipient, olFolderContacts)
Set olItems = olFolder.Items

Set row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportedContacts").Range("a2:G2")

For Each olItem In olItems    'This Line throws an automation error
    With olItem
        If .Class = olContact Then
            row = Array(.FirstName, _
                        .LastName, _
                        .CompanyName, _
                        .BusinessAddressState, _
                        Replace(.Anniversary, "1/1/4501", ""), _
                        .Categories, _
                        .Email1Address)
        End If
    End With
    row = row.Offset(1, 0)
Next

Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olRecipient = Nothing
Set olItems = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing


End Sub
```

Is there a way to specify the shared folder and get data from it?
(Note - I know this code doesn't get the data into a CSV - just the Macro Enabled book.  That'll be next.)

Comment: Do you need to use VBA because I would’ve thought PowerAutomate/Logic Apps would be a better option. I’m not 100% sure if a connector will do it for you but you should take a look … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/

Comment: @Skin I am just a lot more comfortable in vba and thought it might be something simple as I'm not as familiar with the outlook object library. Haven't used Power Automate before.

Comment: @niton Using a link the answer from the link you provided did the trick! I will post the code that worked as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it works beautifully! From niton's comment I found the last option in the following link most helpful.
https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

Here's the code:

```
Sub NavigationFolderFind()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objPane As Outlook.NavigationPane
Dim objModule As Outlook.ContactsModule
Dim olItems As Items
Dim olItem As Object
Dim i As Integer, g As Integer
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set objPane = olApp.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleContacts)

With objModule.NavigationGroups
    
        For g = 1 To .Count
        Set objGroup = .Item(g)
    
            For i = 1 To objGroup.NavigationFolders.Count
            Set objnavfolder = objGroup.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
                
            Debug.Print objnavfolder.DisplayName
            If objnavfolder.DisplayName = "Matt Prater - Matt's File" Then
             Set contactfolder = objnavfolder.Folder
        
            End If
            Next
        Next
End With

etc, etc, etc
End Sub
```

My only gripe with it is that I don't think it would work with option explicit as not all the variables (objGroup, objnavfolder, contactfolder) are previously declared.  I haven't tried at this point to find all the correct dimensions with which to do this. Just glad it works.